# How should I separate the value of array as even, odd?

Tags: php

**Question**

Currently My output is coming like this **PNL testing 1,10,PNL testing 2,55,** I want to manipulate it and store it in two different variables as a string like:

**$teams** = "PNL testing 1, PNL testing 2";

**$amount** = "10, 55";

Please let me know how should I split in the above format.

**Code**

```
while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $profit = 0;
    $total = 0;
    $loss = 0;
    $final_array = '';
    $final_array .= $teams = $row1['t_name'].",";
    $teams = explode(",", $teams);

    $transact_money = $row1['pnl_amount'];
    $pnl_results = $row1['pnl'];

    $transact_money = explode("|", $transact_money);
    $pnl_results = explode("|", $pnl_results);
    for($i=0; $i<count($transact_money); $i++){
        if($pnl_results[$i]=='Profit'){
            $profit = $profit + $transact_money[$i];
        }else{
            $loss = $loss + $transact_money[$i];
        }//end if
    }//end for..
    $team_profits = $profit - $loss.",";
    $final_array .= $team_profits;

    echo $final_array;
}
```

Comment: Why not split out the results inside the While loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
$s = "PNL testing 1,10,PNL testing 2,55";
$res = array();
$result = preg_match_all("{([\w\s\d]+),(\d+)}", $s, $res);
$teams  = join(', ', $res[1]); //will be "PNL testing 1, PNL testing 2"
$amount = join(', ', $res[2]); //will be "10, 55"
```

Comment: thanks that's working but when the value increases from **PNL testing 1,10,PNL testing 2,25** to **PNL testing 1,10,PNL testing 2,25,Faltu team,99** still it shows only 2 values in each variable. Is there anyways to make $res dynamic? Also variable **$final_array** stores the value **"PNL testing 1,10,PNL testing 2,55"** and display it perfectly inside while loop. Can you guide me through to what should I be doing so that I can print off the value outside the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "PNL testing 1,10,PNL testing 2,55,";
preg_match_all("/(PNL testing \d+),(\d+),/", $string, $result);
$teams = implode(",", $result[1]);
$amount = implode(",", $result[2]);
```

Comment: thanks that's working but when the value increases from PNL testing 1,10,PNL testing 2,25 to PNL testing 1,10,PNL testing 2,25,Faltu team,99 still it shows only 2 values in each variable. Is there anyways to make $res dynamic? Also variable $final_array stores the value "PNL testing 1,10,PNL testing 2,55" and display it perfectly inside while loop. Can you guide me through to what should I be doing so that I can print off the value outside the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Less fancy than RegExp, but more obvious:

```
$final_array = "PNL testing 1,10,PNL testing 2,55";

$final_array_array = explode(',', $final_array);

$teams = array();
$amount = array();
$index = 0;

foreach ($final_array_array as $item) {
    switch ($index) {
        case 0:
            $teams[] = $item;
            break;
        case 1:
            $amount[] = $item;
    }
    $index = 1-$index;
}
```